# How to automate the action on a canvas object, when the canvas element has no name or ID in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, webdriver

I want to automate the testing for a digital signature, which is a canvas element.

Can anyone provide me with sample code, which could be used.

I have tried,

```
selenium.clickAt(),
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div/canvas")).click();
```

both threw an element not found exception for me...

Source Code of the page, for the Canvas region:

```
<table>
<tr class="tdbg" valign="middle"  bgcolor="#D4D4D4" height="1px">
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"></td>
<td width="90%" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
  <div align="center" id="electronicSignImage">
    <div>Please use mouse to draw your Signature &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ds" align="center">
      <iframe id="elecsign"  align='middle' style="border:1px #9E9E9E solid;
      padding:10px;" height='180' width='200' scrolling='no'
      src='http://<pdftest.anotherwebsite.com>//signature/index.php?signid=<something>'
      class="required" ></iframe>
      <input type="hidden" name="ds" value="<something">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td width="5%"  bgcolor="#D4D4D4"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tdbg" valign="middle"  bgcolor="#D4D4D4" >
  <td width="5%" height="1px" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">&nbsp;</td>
  <td  bgcolor="#D4D4D4" height="1px" width="80%" >&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="5%" height="1px" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you say it didn't work, do you mean that it did not throw an exception, but did not do anything, or was there an exception stating that the element can not be found, or something else?

Comment: @SamWoods it did throw an exception, stating, the element was not found..

Comment: Did you try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//canvas")).click()`?

Comment: @user246, not working...modified and tried.!:)

Comment: I will add the source code part for that canvas region...Hope, that will help !

Comment: It might help if the source code were to show the canvas element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the Canvas element was embedded in a Frame..So, had to switch to Frame and then click on the Canvas!! That was the solution, for the issue...

Answer (score 2):

The Canvas element display issue in Selenium 2.28 has been solved in Selenium 2.29 version.
The following code did work for me. The `driver` object is a Firefox driver.

```
Actions actionBuilder=new Actions(driver);          
Action drawOnCanvas=actionBuilder
                .contextClick(wbCanvas)
                .moveToElement(wbCanvas,8,8)
                .clickAndHold(wbCanvas)
                .moveByOffset(120, 120)
                .moveByOffset(60,70)
                .moveByOffset(-140,-140)
                .release(wbCanvas)
                .build();
drawOnCanvas.perform();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..!!:) late thanks though..:)

Comment: what is wbCanvas in here

Answer (score 1):

Drawing 3 points which will create a polygon and the last double click ends the drawing process code described bellow:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of canvas"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(element,135,15) //start points x axis and y axis. 
              .click()
              .moveByOffset(200, 60) // 2nd points (x1,y1)
              .click()
              .moveByOffset(100, 70)// 3rd points (x2,y2)
              .doubleClick()
              .build();
    drawAction.perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to the fact that I'm a lazy coder, I always record my cases with Selenium IDE and find the best way to locate the WebElements I use.

Use the "Target" Dropdown to alter the way you address them and the "Find" Button to assure it's working.

Also make sure that you use the last version of Selenium/Browser